# How phase lag varies depending on frequency?

Tags: frequency, oscillators

I am going through E. Hecht's "Optics", and I am currently trying to solve some problems from the book. However, I need help with one of them.

**The equation for a driven damped oscillator is**

$m_e\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + m_e\gamma\frac{dx}{dt} + m_ew_0^2x = qE(t)$

**(c) Derive an expression for the phase lag, $\alpha$ and discuss how $\alpha$ varies as $w<<w_0$ to $w=w_0$ to $w>>w_0$.**

I got the following result for the phase lag:

$\alpha = arctan(\frac{\gamma w}{(w_0^2 - w^2)})$

I have the solution manual, and this result, according to it, is correct.

However, I do not understand how $\alpha$ should vary.

According to the solution manual:

**$\alpha$ ranges continuously from 0 to $\pi/2$ to $\pi$.**

But:

1. $arctan$ function range from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$. How it then can be continuous from 0 to $\pi/2$ to $\pi$?
2. For $w=w_0$ case we actually have division by 0. So, again, how it then can be continuous?
3. How to derive exect values for $\alpha$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The arctan function is discontinuous at $π/2$, so I'd imagine that the solution manual was referred to two ranges, $0$ to $π/2$ and $π/2$ to $π$. "Phase lag" sounds like an absolute value as phase "lags". The arctan function is multi-valued: $2πN - π/2$ to $2πn + π/2$ where n is any integer. So the ranges you choose to use is subject to interpretation in context of the physical question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

1. As xxyzzy pointed out, $\arctan$ is a multivalued function, so you could add any multiple of $\pi$ to it's result based on the physical problem. In fact, if you define

$$
\alpha(\omega) = \begin{cases} \arctan \left ( \frac{\gamma\omega}{\omega_0^2 - \omega^2} \right ), \; 0 \leq \omega < \omega_0 \\
\pi/2, \; \omega = \omega_0 \\
\arctan \left ( \frac{\gamma\omega}{\omega_0^2 - \omega^2} \right ) + \pi, \; \omega > \omega_0
\end{cases}
$$

you can see that this function $\alpha(\omega)$ will be continuous for every positive value of $\omega$, which I believe is the function the solution manual is referring to (this way $\alpha$ will be always nonnegative aswell).

2. Indeed, your $\alpha(\omega)$ won't be defined at $\omega = \omega_0$. However, in the strict mathematical sense, a function is continuous if for every $a$ in it's domain we have $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$. So $\alpha$ *is* continuous since $\omega_0$ is not in the domain of $\alpha$.
3. You can derive some exact values of $\alpha$ at the special "points": $\omega = 0$, $\omega \to \infty$ and left and right limits at $\omega = \omega_0$.